# Modelling steps in a process

Tags: machine-learning

So I'm not really new to machine learning, but I'm faced with a task for which I have little knowledge of existing solutions.

Basically, I want to be able to learn all the steps in a process. For examples, what are the steps to go from state A to state Z. I would like to learn such sequences from the sequences produced by some users. For example, ten users attempt to go from A to Z, producing 10 different "traces", and I want to learn the ideal sequence.

I know of the STRIPS approach, which uses logic to represent states and steps. But do you know of any other approaches? Using graphs, or decision trees, or I don't know? Probabilistic approaches maybe? I'm curious about alternatives.

I didn't have much success in my searches so far, maybe because I lack the appropriate keywords. Is there a specific name for what I'm describing?

Best;